# dataset on Credit Default Swap

Tags: data, cds, credit, sovereign-cds

I would like to have the CDS for the main countries. Do you know where I could find these data free to use?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Bloomberg `CDSX`, or try a quick search:

- http://www.cnbc.com/sovereign-credit-default-swaps/
- http://www.swapsinfo.org/

Comment: But I need the historical series

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at

- [DataGrapple](https://www.datagrapple.com/) (there are sovereigns, for sure)
- [OTCStreaming](http://www.otcstreaming.com/)

for data on credit default swaps.

Comment: Thanks but datagrapple does not allow me to download them (or I did not manage to do that) and OTCStreaming does not have the data for the main sovrein cds spread.